# Are there published standards for "cuts" of seafood similar to the NAMP guide?

Tags: seafood, shopping

I've been using [the NAMP Meat Buyers Guide](https://www.amazon.ca/Buyers-Guide-American-Processors-Association/dp/0471696250) ([pdf](https://www.thelivestockinstitute.org/uploads/4/9/9/2/49923305/meat-buyers-guide.pdf)) to specify to butchers what, exactly, I'm looking for.  That guide is simply an organized list of unambiguous names and descriptions of meat cuts.  Using the terminology from that guide works great, at least in BC, especially when placing orders in advance over the phone.  I can't think of a time I've gotten the wrong thing from a butcher when I've used the terminology from that guide.

I'm looking for a similar guide for seafood.  I live in BC where there is plenty of good seafood around.  There seems to be little agreement, however, about what, exactly, almost any terminology about edible seafood means.  Even the terms "boned", "fillet", "steak", "flash frozen", "farmed", "wild", and "sockeye" seem to have rather fungible meanings along the supply chain here.

Is there a guide that specifies seafood for the food service industry in North America?  Is there such a guide for anywhere in the world?